# Sql query for getting top X 'distinct' values of one field when sorting by another?

Tags: sql

I have a table in a db that has an int field, a non-unique id field plus others. I need to sort by the int field then get the top X distinct id fields.

So for example if these are my table values (sorted by the intfld):

```
id  intfld
CC  1
AA  2
CC  3
AA  4
FF  4
OO  5
EE  6
KK  6
```

And I wanted the top 3 id's the returned values would be CC,AA,FF.

I tried distinct and group by but I don't think they will work. Maybe I'm missing something obvious since I don't work in SQL a lot.

Can I do this with a sql statement?

Thanks.

Edit: I'm using Oracle.

Comment: "It depends", in this case on your DBMS.  Are you using MySQL, SQL Sever, Oracle, PostgreSQL, SQLite, ... ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should get you on the right track:

```
SELECT 
  ID AS MyDistinctValue, 
  MIN(intfld) AS MySort
FROM
  MyTable
GROUP BY ID
ORDER BY MySort
```

Answer (score 0):

What if you had those results :

```
A, 1
B, 2
C, 3
D, 3
E, 4
```

Would you select C or D? It would be random, and therefore, usually not a good solution. I'd definitely rather to pick all four (A, B, C, D) instead with a query like this one :

```
WITH TT AS (
    SELECT id, RANK() OVER(ORDER BY MIN(intfld)) AS R
    FROM YourTable
    GROUP BY ID
)
SELECT id
FROM TT
WHERE R <= 3;
```

Which would select A, B, C and D.